# rtw_8821ce: firmware failed to leave lps state

Tags: 22.04, firmware

I have the RTL8821ce Wifi and Bluetooth adapter under Ubuntu 22.04.1 Jammy Jellyfish. The adapter is working. However, I have the message in the systemd log:

```
rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
```

I have no idea what it means. I suppose I have to wait to the next release of linux-firmware package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88/issues/61

I suggest that you try the possible solution involving power saving. Let's disable power saving to see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Reboot and tell us if the message persists.

Comment: It has fixed the issue. I have not seen this error after reboot.

Comment: Thanks for solution.